# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position') with ThreeJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm trying to integrate a 3D model in the background of the hero section of my site. it works except that when I manually change the size of the window, the 3D model does not adapt to the new size. The other problem which is possibly related to the first one is that I get this error message in the console and it refers to line 69 of my code in the 'three.js' file:
In the console I get this error message:

[image]
[image]

my priority would be to solve the problem of the 3D model which does not adapt to the size of the screen. As for the error message, it's less important if it still works. But ideally two would solve both problems.

Do you have an idea ?

```js
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/addons/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

const heroSection = document.querySelector("#hero-section");
heroSection.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// Importation du model 3D
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
let model;
loader.load(
  "./scene.gltf",
  function (gltf) {
    model = gltf.scene;

    scene.add(gltf.scene);
  },
  undefined,
  function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
);

//Control des mouvements
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableZoom = false;

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
scene.add(ambientLight, light);

// position de la camera
camera.position.set(0, 1, 5);
// camera.position.set(0, 4, 8);
controls.update();

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  model.position.y = -2;
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth; /* permet un scroll automatique souple video : 1h 07mn 50 */
  scroll-padding-top: 100px; /* On lui dit : arrête le scroll auto à 100px pour tenir compte de la hauteur de la navbar. 
  ("PROJECTES" appaît en haut et sous la navbar quand on click sur le lein "Projects" de la navbar.) */
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-family: "roboto", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 20px 10vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9;
  transition: 0.4s; /* pour le background noire - vidéo : 1h 09 */
}

nav.bg {
  /* Voir vidéo : 1h 09 */
  background-color: #000;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
}

.links-container {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  gap: 10px;
}

.links {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.links:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* hero-section */
#hero-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

#hero-section canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.hero-headline {
  font-family: "sahitya", serif;
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-secondary-line {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 25px 0 50px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.btn {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  width: fit-content; /*(pas utile pur moi : explication : https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/width/#:~:text=the%20fit-content%20value*/
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: block; /*pour faire fonctionner 'margin:auto' */
  margin: auto;
}

.btn.light {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.btn.transparent {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" theme="light">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Three JS Personal Portfolio</title>

    <!-- google font CDN -->

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100;300;500;600;700;800;900&family=Roboto:wght@400;700&family=Sahitya&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- font awesome CDN -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SzlrxWUlpfuzQ+pcUCosxcglQRNAq/DZjVsC0lE40xsADsfeQoEypE+enwcOiGjk/bSuGGKHEyjSoQ1zVisanQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

    <!-- local CSS file(s) -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!-- Tree Js -->
    <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.6.3/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>

    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@latest/build/three.module.js",
          "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@latest/examples/jsm/"
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <img src="img\Logo.png" alt="" class="logo" />
        <ul class="links-container">
          <li class="link-item"><a href="#hero-section" class="links">Home</a></li>
          <li class="link-item"><a href="#Projects-section" class="links">Projects</a></li>
          <li class="link-item"><a href="#" class="links">About</a></li>
          <li class="link-item"><a href="#" class="links">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- hero section -->
      <main id="hero-section">
        <div class="hero-content">
          <h1 class="hero-headline">Take your business onligne</h1>
          <p class="hero-secondary-line">The only person you need to help you with your business</p>

          <a href="#" class="btn">Let's chat</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Position du canvas dans le navigateur -->
      </main>
    </header>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not resizing is because of the error. It's trying to update your model position, but the model isn't defined at that point, so it errors and doesn't move any further.

I think you're calling that `animate()` function at the end before your async file loading is complete. Because the rest of the code is running while the object is loading, it hits that last line, runs the animate function, and fails because the model is undefined at that point. If you want that to happen after the model is loaded, you'll need to move it into the success function.

Comment: I would like to use an async function like this:
```
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

async function main() {
const loader = new GLTFLoader();
const modelData = await loader('models/pig.glb');

console.log(modelData);
}

main().catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
```
Could you help me to adapt my code ?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem of the error in the 'console' with a condition:
`if (model) {
     model.position.y = -2;
   }`
but the size of the model still does not adapt to the size of the window. An idea ?

Comment: avec ce code à la fin du script, le model s'adapte:
`window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  // Met à jour la taille du renderer
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  // Met à jour l'aspect de la caméra
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  // Appelle la méthode updateProjectionMatrix sur la caméra
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});
`